# How to format \n as a line break in my markdown returned via a GraphQL query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-management-system, html-parsing, gatsby

I am using Contentful and Gatsby for context. In Contentful a user writes a bunch of content where they can see it preview nicely in the editor. The GraphQL data from it returns something like this

> `<p>Hello World</p>\n<p><strong>Foo Bar </strong>\n999 172 St. NW\nEdmonton, AB</p>\n<p><strong>Sushi</strong>\n2020 87 Ave.\nEdmonton</p>`

I would like to format all the \n (the line breaks) so that the previewed content inside my website looks exactly like the preview in this Content Editor Platform. Right now I don't have any line breaks so all my content would be a giant word blob if I did not format my p tags.

What is the best solution to create these line breaks or to convert all \n to br elements so that each time I have a \n a new line is created on my site?

Currently I am using *dangerouslySetInnerHTML* attribute on a div to render the content from the example given on the Gatsby site. And styling the html element `br` does not work.

Comment: What happens if you do two spaces followed by a return in the contentful markdown editor where ever you want a newline?

Comment: I can try that but why would I have to do that? What if someone else is writing content, do I have to tell them to press the spacebar twice followed by a return to create a proper linebreak? That seems crazy

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. It appears that you're already using something like remark in your GraphQL to convert markdown text to HTML, but you don't specify. How are you displaying the content here? HTML is largely whitespace-insensitive—your newlines shouldn't impact the rendered content. Are you looking for these to be converted to `<br />` elements?

Comment: @Aquasar It's unclear which kind of contentful text fields you are referring to, but if they are markdown, two spaces followed by a return is how you would get a newline to render.

Comment: Let me clarify, I am using gatsby-transformer-remark. I am then using dangerouslySetInnterHTML and passing in data.description.childMarkdownRemark.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and the fix was super easy. Just add `white-space: pre;` style to you div with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. At least this worked for me. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the note, I will try. Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [rich text react renderer](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer) with the Rich Text field, you can define custom rendering for your text nodes using the following line in options:

```
const options = {
 renderText: text => text.split('\n').flatMap((text, i) => [i > 0 && <br />, 
 text])
}
```

This will find and replace \n with 
 in your text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code based on **@Sasha Ko**'s Answer.

**GraphQL**

```
textField {
  childMarkdownRemark {
    html
  }
}
```

**JSX**

```js
<div className="multiline-text"
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: textField.childMarkdownRemark.html }}></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.multiline-text{
   white-space: pre;
}
```